# Electrophilic Aromatic substitution reactions of aromatic compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, electrophilic-substitution

*Benzene* and *substituted benzene* (**phenols, aromatic ethers, benzaldehyde, aromatic ketones like acetophenone, benzoic acid, aniline and nitrobenzene**) generally can undergo electrophilic Aromatic substitution reactions.

Now among all of these only benzene and *aromatic ethers* can undergo **Friedel-Crafts alkylation reactions** (or I'm wrong?).

My question is do all of the Aromatic compounds undergo **halogenation**,**nitration** and **sulphonation** cause these reactions as far as I know fall under electrophilic Aromatic substitution reactions.

Comment: You are asking far too general. You know the mechanisms of FC and electrophilic substitution. They always work, unless there is a reaction with a substituent instead of the aromatic core. That you have to decide for each case individually.

Comment: Btw. you *do* know the difference between activated and desactivated aromats? (You usually wouldn't if you haven't learned about FC-*Acylation* yet. In that case just wait a week until yout teacher gets to it.)

Comment: I do know about it..there are some groups that activate the ring and there are some that deactivate the ring.like OH,NH2 OCH3 etc these groups...they are electron donating and are activating..in addition are ortho para directing...and NO2,CHO,COOH etc ..these groups are electron withdrawing and are deactivating and meta directing...but halogens are an exception..cause they are electron withdrawing and still are ortho para directing and there inductive effect is stronger than resonance effect.hope I'm right.

Comment: With the right conditions you can nitrate pretty much any aromatic unless there is a substituent that is unstable to the reation conditions.